# Can't see notifications on notifications bar

Tags: notification-area

I have messed up with my notification bar such that its not showing time and battery status.

> How can i get them back?
>   I am using gnome-classic for now.   Here is the screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstall indicator-datetimejust in case you have removed it unknowingly, it is best to run the install command again.

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime
```

Next, we are going to reconfigure the date time:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

For battery indicator

```
 sudo apt-get install indicator-power
```

then

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power active true
```

This command will restart unity panel and re-showing up the lost indicators

```
sudo killall unity-panel-service
```

If the command above has no effect reboot and check